# Jquery loses brackets on data after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, square-bracket

I'm having a data text file like this:

```
[[1412525998000,"91.83"],[1412525998000,"91.83"],[1412525997000,"90.14"]...ETC
```

When I get this data trough ajax request something weird happens. The 'data' variable becomes this:

```
1412525998000,91.831412525998000,91.831412525997000,90.14...ETC
```

For some reason it just dumps all square-brackets.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mydata.php",
    data: {},
    success: function(data) { 
        $('#debug_div').html(data);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

I've never seen anything similar so I wonder what could be causing this?

Comment: Can we see the code of `mydata.php` ?

Comment: It's just a file that outputs this: [[1412525998000,"91.83"],[1412525998000,"91.83"],[1412525997000,"90.14"], ... to the end... ]

Comment: To avoid this kind of mistake in the future, debug your variables through the console, not the DOM. ie: console.log(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying type `json` so jQuery is automatically parsing the response JSON and giving you the resulting array as `data`. You then pass it to `.html()` which is casting the array as a string, causing the output you see.

To demonstrate:

```
document.write( [1, 2, 3] );
```

Outputs

```
1, 2, 3
```

Your array is perfectly intact, it's only when you cast it as a string that you see the result you have. For example:

```
console.log(data[0][0]); // 1412525998000
console.log(data[0][1]); // 91.83
```

Refer to [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).

Comment: so I need to call it as text?

Comment: No, `data` is your array, as it should be. It's only when you try to output the whole thing into HTML that it will be converted to a string.